# Trying to print invalid email address from a list using c++?

Tags: c++, string, boolean-logic

I am trying to print a list of invalid emailaddress (which has a space and does not have a @ or .) from a list of email addresses. The list has a few email addresses which have spaces, and no '@' or '.' but still it does not print anything.

```
    //Declaring boolean variables
    bool atPresent;
    bool periodPresent;
    bool spacePresent;
    
    string emailid = someemailfrom a list;
    atPresent = false;
    periodPresent = false;
    spacePresent = false;
    
    //looking for @
    size_t foundAt = emailid.find('@');
    if (foundAt != string::npos) {
        atPresent = true;
    }
    
    //looking for '.'
    size_t foundPeriod = emailid.find('.');
    if (foundPeriod != string::npos) {
        periodPresent = true;
    }
    
    //looking for ' '
    size_t foundSpace = emailid.find(' ');
    if (foundSpace != string::npos) {
        spacePresent = true;
    }
    
    //checking to see if all conditions match
    if ( (atPresent == false) && (periodPresent == false) && (spacePresent == true)) {
        cout << emailid << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Minor nit unrelated to your question: You can `if ()` on `bool`s without the equality operator. `if (myBool == true)` is the same as `if (myBool)`, `if (myBool == false)` is the same as `if (!myBool)`

Comment: Why not return false immediately if there is no `@` sign?  Similarly if there is no `.`?  The only reason I see for waiting until the very end to figure out if the string is valid is if you want to accumulate all the errors and report them.

Comment: Another thing is that you can just make a single pass through the string and not make 3 separate passes if you rearranged the testing logic.

Comment: Unrelated as far as programming is concernd: email addresses are actually allowed to contain spaces when quoted and are not required to contain a dot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(atPresent == false) && (periodPresent == false) && (spacePresent == true)
```

Is wrong. It is only true, when *all* of the three criteria for an invalid adress are met. But an address is invalid as soon as *at least on criteria* is met. This would be

```
(atPresent == false) || (periodPresent == false) || (spacePresent == true)
```

And simplified:

```
!atPresent || !periodPresent || spacePresent
```

Answer (score 1):

replace && statements by || statements : you are only printing those which doesn't have @ AND have a space AND have a period.  You should use a regex, so you can do it on one line, and know how to use them is always usefull when you try to validate user data